# Sufficient Condition for Uniform Integrability $\mathcal{L}^1$-boundedness

Tags: probability, lp-spaces, uniform-integrability

I saw the following proof showing necessary and sufficient conditions for Uniform Integrability:

[image]

And was just wondering does uniform integrability still hold if we ONLY have $\mathcal{L}^1$-boundedness and not the condition 2?

I.e. Is $\mathcal{L}^1$-boundedness alone for the family $\mathcal{X}$ of measurable functions sufficient for Uniform Integrability of $\mathcal{X}$?

If so - how could you go about showing it (cause I've been stuck on trying to show this)...or more than likely...

If not, why does this "intuitively" not work and could you please give a counter example?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Does not work. Counterexample: $X_n=n\mathbf 1_{A_n}$ where $P(A_n)=\frac1n$.

Comment: Thanks for that counter example! I completely understand the proof given and the counter example, but is there any chance you could give me an intuition or explanation of how/why condition 2 is needed and what it actually does to guarantee uniform integrability holds?

Comment: Condition 2. is what makes uniform integrability stronger than boundedness in $L^1$. Is your question, why the former is relevant rather than the latter in many contexts?

Comment: Hi Did, sorry for the late reply! Yes that is one part of my question. But I am also, trying to understand the difference between what UI means for the tails and what $L^1$ boundedness means for the tails of the family of random variables, and how one requirement regarding the properties that tails must satisfy is stronger than the other. Thanks for taking the time to read and reply.